# How to sort XML content by 2 Attributes in C# using Linq?

Tags: c#, xml, sorting, linq-to-xml

I'm new in C# and want to sort an XML in memory by *START* Attribute but I need to take into account that when *START_PLUSDAY* Attribute exists.

Here is my XML:

```
<SCHEDULE>
   <PROGS>
      <PROG START="07:00:00" END="08:00:00">
          <ID></ID>
          <DATA>...</DATA>
             <STUFF>...</STUFF>
      </PROG>
      <PROG START="01:00:00" START_PLUSDAY="1" END="02:00:00" END_PLUSDAY="1">
          <ID></ID>
          <DATA>...</DATA>
             <STUFF>...</STUFF>
      </PROG>
   </PROGS>
</SCHEDULE>
```

The result I want should look like this:

```
<SCHEDULE>
   <PROGS>
      <PROG START="07:00:00" END="08:00:00">
          <ID></ID>
          <DATA>...</DATA>
             <STUFF>...</STUFF>
      </PROG>
      <PROG START="01:00:00" START_PLUSDAY="1" END="02:00:00" END_PLUSDAY="1">
          <ID></ID>
          <DATA>...</DATA>
             <STUFF>...</STUFF>
      </PROG>
   </PROGS>
</SCHEDULE>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XElement progs = doc.Descendants("PROGS").FirstOrDefault();

            List<XElement> sortedProg = progs.Elements("PROG")
                .OrderBy(x => (int?)x.Attribute("START_PLUSDAY"))
                .ThenBy(x => (DateTime)x.Attribute("START")).ToList();
            XElement newProgs = new XElement("PROGS", sortedProg);

            progs.ReplaceWith(newProgs);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you very much. For my use i can skip progs.ReplaceWith(newProgs); and just parse foreach (XElement xe in newProgs.Descendants("PROGRAMME")). Thanks again!!!